# Passing PHP GET into a jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, tabs, get

I'm using a bit of jquery code which uses li items to select which tab is displayed. the "tabs" are just divs. This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            //When page loads...
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
            $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

            //On Click Event
            $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
                $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
                $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

                var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
                $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Where it says li:first and adds the active class to it, i'm trying to figure out how i can change which "tab" gets displayed first depending on a PHP GET result: `<?php $tab = $_GET['tab']; ?>`

"tab" will be a number 1,2,3 or 4. ie. tab 1, tab 2, etc...so how can i use this PHP variable with jQuery to choose which tab to make Active?

Thanks

Comment: And how do you make it active in js (let's suppose you don't have php at all)?

Comment: Well it just picks the first li, like it says above. but i'd like to change that depending on a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this (assuming the 'tab' GET parameter is an index):

```
$("ul.tabs li:nth-child(<?= $_GET['tab'] ?>)").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:nth-child(<?= $_GET['tab'] ?>)").show(); //Show first tab content
```

Comment: absolutely what i meant! perfect